# Powershell could not saveas excel after data written

Tags: excel, powershell

I am a brand newbie to powershell. I am trying to generate a report to gather all printers' information in our environment. The report is well generated by opening Excel worksheet; however, it fails to save and simply jumps onto close

Below script I used to generate a report:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $True
$xls = $xl.Workbooks.Add()
$Sh = $xls.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Sh.Name = "Printer Info"
.
.
.
.
$xls.SaveAs("C:\temp\Test.xlsx", $xlFixedFormat)
$xls.Close()
$xl.Quit()
```

Error message received is what below:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Sh.Name = "Printer Info"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $xls.SaveAs("C:\temp\Test.xlsx", $xlFixedFormat)
Exception calling "SaveAs" with "2" argument(s): "SaveAs method of Workbook class failed"
At line:1 char:1
+ $xls.SaveAs("C:\temp\Test.xlsx", $xlFixedFormat)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

The script works find in Windows Server 2008 R2 without any issues; however, it simply fails to work in Windows 7 64 bit.

I would really appreciate if I get an assistance asap.

Comment: Most of the article refers creating a directory structure as "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop"; but, creating of a directory structure did not help me fixing the issue.

Comment: Did you try `$xls.SaveAs("C:\temp\Test.xlsx")`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, it was tried only with the path and file like you mentioned; however, had no luck. The strange thing I noticed today is that the same script works fine when I execute it from Powershell ISE without any change; however, it fails to run only through Powershell cli. Appreciate your time.